# Retag "milesdavis" with "miles-davis"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

With [my edit](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/283) to a question, I tried to remove the tag [milesdavis](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milesdavis) and add [miles-davis](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miles-davis) instead. This was not possible: the system informed me that the tag names are too similar, and that I should head to Meta if something should be changed about this tag.

**Proposal:** Rename [milesdavis](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milesdavis) to [miles-davis](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miles-davis).

All our musician tags use the hyphen (`-`) where a space should be; it’s more readable; most SE sites seem to hyphenate their tags.

Comment: We can't burn tags, but a synonym was assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Dashes should be used to separate the words/names of an artist or group rather than jamming them all together.